# How to avoid the need of an auxiliary newtype when matching this Backpack signature?

Tags: haskell, haskell-backpack

I'm using the new Backpack module system along with Cabal 2. I have the follwing signature:

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
signature Streamy where

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

data Stream :: * -> (* -> *) -> * -> *

instance Monad m => Functor (Stream o m)
instance Monad m => Applicative (Stream o m)
instance Monad m => Monad (Stream o m)
instance MonadIO m => MonadIO (Stream o m) 
instance MonadTrans (Stream o)
```

I'm trying to match it with the concrete [`Stream`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.1.4.5/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html#t:Stream) type from [streaming](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.1.4.5), like this:

```
import Streaming (Of(..))
import qualified Streaming as Q

type Stream o m r = Q.Stream (Of o) m r
```

However, this gives me the error

> Illegal parameterized type synonym in implementation of abstract data.
>   (Try eta reducing your type synonym so that it is nullary)

It seems that the type synonym can't have parameters. I need at least one  however, because the `o` is sitting inside the `Of` instead of being a direct parameter of `Q.Stream`.

I can solve the problem by defining an adapter newtype:

```
{-# language GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
newtype S o m r = S { unS :: Q.Stream (Of o) m r } 
        deriving (Functor,Applicative,Monad,MonadIO,MonadTrans)

type Stream = S
```

Is there another way that doesn't require defining the newtype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there isn't a way to avoid the newtype. The Backpack [thesis](https://github.com/ezyang/thesis/releases/tag/final) clearly states that type synonyms are required to be nullary (section 6.2.4 "Subtyping rules"):

> the implementing type synonyms are required to be nullary: for
>   example, type `M a = a` is not a valid implementation of the abstract
>   data `M a`, but `type M = Maybe :: * -> *` is. This restriction stems
>   from an old design decision in Haskell to not support type level
>   lambdas. This restriction greatly helps type inference, since given
>   the type equality `t a = s b`, we can now conclude that `t = s` and `a = b`
>   (this property is called generativity).

Also related, in section B.2 "Challenges":

> Translucency: A feature not supported in Backpack’14 but supported in
>   Backpack’17 is the ability to use a type synonym to implement an
>   abstract data type. This introduces a form of “translucency”, where
>   the abstract data type is opaque while the implementation is unknown,
>   and transparent afterwards. For example, in Section 2.3, we
>   demonstrated how we could instantiate a generic regular expression
>   matcher to match on strings. Inside the implementation of the matcher,
>   we knew nothing about the abstract type `Str`; after instantiating it,
>   the accept function transparently accepts `String` arguments.